# Plural or singular namespace names in C++

Tags: c++, namespaces, naming-conventions

Suppose we have a namespace containing several policy classes:

```
namespace loggingPolicy {
    class OnWrite {...};
    class OnReadWrite {...};
    etc.
} // namespace
```

The name `LoggingPolicy::OnWrite` makes sense. On the other hand, this namespace is really a collection of classes and the name `loggingPolicies` would reflect that better. Which one should be chosen?

Although I do not generally follow the Google C++ Style Guide, I did look up its [naming conventions for namespaces](https://google.github.io/styleguide/cppguide.html#Namespace_Names), but it did not have anything to say on the issue.

P.S. I am working on an independent project and am not bound to any organization's guidelines. However, my framework will hopefully be used by many people, so good notation style is important.

Comment: Isn't this a totally opinion based question?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I was not sure if it was. If the answer is clear-cut, I want to find it out.

Answer (score 6):

There is no technical argument for or against any of this choice. Basically it's a packaging choice, like a library name or a header name.

There are some consistency arguments in favor of the singular if you place yourself on the side of your users:

- the user will use your LoggingPolicy framework.
- if you'd embed it in its own library, the user will use the Policy library
- if you'd expose all your declarations in a unique header, it would be LoggingPolicy.h
- if you'd use the plural, it will confuse the user, because he already use the std namespace (and not the stds or standards namespace, even if it encapsulates many different standard areas). Same for headers: all the c++ header names are in singular (e.g algorithm, iterator, string are all in singular despite offering many different algorithms, iterators or strings.

Finally, today you expose only policy classes. But what if you'd expose also some common helper classes, or utility functions ? The plural would then give the impression that these object are alternative policies, while in reality they only complete the policy which it was used for.

Comment: I noticed that you used `LoggingPolicy` instead of `loggingPolicy`. Is that intentional? I thought that lower first letter was preferable, since that allows easy distinction from a class... (even though classes are namespaces as well, but still...)

Comment: No this is not intentional: i'm standing in front of my smartphone and the screen was not big enough to check the capitalisation convention that you use ;-)  I tend to use either lowercase with underscore or CapitalizedWords (like for classes) and i reserve initialLowercase for member functions. but you have to be consistent with your own conventions here.